# Kotlin referential equality behavior on Int with values between -128 to 127

Tags: kotlin

I'm giving myself until 12:00AM to learn and get productive (hopefully) on kotlin.

Following https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-docs.pdf I tried these snippets on page 17. Could anyone please help me understand why `===` returns `true` if a value is between `-128` to `127`?

The following indeed prints `false`:

```
val a: Int = 10000
val boxedA: Int? = a            // Integer@445
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a     // Integer@447 why?
print(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // false
```

However changing `a` to any value between `-128` to `127` always prints `true`:

```
val a: Int = -128
val boxedA: Int? = a            // Integer@445
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a     // Integer@445 why?
print(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // true!
```

It seems to me if `Int` value is outside the bounds of `-128` to `127` (Java byte) kotlin creates a new object on assignment does making the reference not equal.

Answer (score 9):

See the Java source code of `Integer.valueOf()` which is reponsible for boxing int values. The javadoc says:

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127

So boxed integers in that range are always the same object if they have the same numeric value.

In Kotlin, you should compare boxed Integers with `==` and not with `===`.