# What does the === operator do in Kotlin?

Tags: syntax, kotlin

What does operator `===` do in Kotlin? How does it work? Can we check reference equality?

```
val a: Int = 10000
print(a === a) // Prints 'true'
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
print(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // !!!Prints 'false'!!!
```

but in case:

```
var a : Int = 1000
var b : Int = 1000
println(a === b) // print 'true' !!!
```

`val a: Int = 1000` and `val b: Int = 1000` is not in range `-128..127`, but still `===` is true or compiler in some cases understand that it can be taken one value?

Comment: same as Java's "reference equality"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As [documented](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html), it represents **Referential Equality**:

> Referential equality is checked by the === operation (and its negated counterpart !==). a === b evaluates to true if and only if a and b point to the same object.

Referential equality means that two references point to the same object. Per instance:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val number1 = Integer(10) // create new instance
    val number2 = Integer(10) // create new instance
    val number3 = number1

    // check if number1 and number2 are Structural equality
    println(number1 == number2) // prints true

    // check if number1 and number2 points to the same object
    // in other words, checks for Referential equality
    println(number1 === number2) // prints false

    // check if number1 and number3 points to the same object
    println(number1 === number3) // prints true
}
```

Compare this to the Java code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer number1 = new Integer(10); // create new instance
    Integer number2 = new Integer(10); // create new instance
    Integer number3 = number1;

    // check if number1 and number2 are Structural equality
    System.out.println(number1.equals(number2)); // prints true

    // check if number1 and number2 points to the same object
    // in other words, checks for Referential equality
    System.out.println(number1 == number2); // prints false

    // check if number1 and number3 points to the same object
    System.out.println(number1 == number3); // prints true
}
```

#### Your example:

Also, as [documented here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation), "boxing of numbers does not preserve identity". So, `boxedA` will have one identity, but `anotherBoxedA` will have another one. Both have structural equality, but not referential equality.

But why the second one works? Because the Kotlin `Int` type corresponds to the Java `int` type. The two variables compared in the second example are primitive type values, not objects. Therefore, for them the reference equality is exactly the same as regular equality.

Comment: That doesn't really explain the OP's behavior. Why are a and b equal, but not boxedA and anotherBoxedA?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure either, but AFAIK, `Int` variables (not `Int?`) are compiled to primitive Java `int` by Kotlin, so there isn't any object involved in the second comparison. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Edited answer to correct the information. Kotlin doesn't do any Int caching on its own, and there's nothing to cache in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @yole. Is there any documentation about it?

Comment: The difference between `Int` and `Int?` is documented here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation

Comment: @JBNizet doesn't the other time this was answered on SO explain why? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35621335/3679676

Comment: @JaysonMinard no, the two questions look different to me. One is about the Integer cache of Java, and the other is about the difference between Int and Int?.

Comment: ah true.  guess people using primitives that may or may not be boxed at different times should avoid ===

Comment: `val a: Int = 1000` is not in range `-128..127`, but still `===` is true or compiler in some cases understand that it can be taken one value?