# Different result of operator '===' in different value 'name' between two value

Tags: kotlin, syntax

My code makes different result when I compare it to another user's one.
([Interesting operator '===' in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670230/interesting-operator-in-kotlin#))

I'm using intellij IDEA.

```
//This is my code
val a: Int = 1
val b: Int? = a
val c: Int? = a
println(b===c) //true

//This is another user's one
val a: Int = 10000
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
print(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) //false
```

I can't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are running code on JVM, this is what happens:

1. `Int?` gets translated to `java.lang.Integer`, `Int` to the primitive `int` type.
2. `val boxedA: Int? = a` becomes `val boxedA: Integer = Integer.valueOf(a)`. (`Integer.valueOf` is how `int`s are boxed).
3. Documentation for `Integer.valueOf`:

   > This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

So 1 gets cached, and multiple calls to `Integer.valueOf(1)` return the same `Integer`; 10000 doesn't (by default).

But really, `===` is very rarely useful.

Comment: wow, I never thought about the number! Thanks for your detailed explanation